# While copying, how to overwrite the existing Excel file with new data?

Tags: python-2.7

While copying an Excel file to another folder if the same name Excel file already exists, then its contents should get updated with new Excel data.

```
shutil.copy('Second.xlsx', self.Folderpath)
```

At `self.Folderpath` location if `Second.xlsx` file is already present then its contents should get updated with recent file's data.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: Do you want to copy a file, overwriting the target if it already exists? Then what does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: Do you mean to say different things in the first and the last paragraphs? To me it seems like they are saying the same, only worded slightly differently.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i am working on excel file. Hence i have given excel example.

Comment: Actual issue is present with     "os.rename(src,dst)"   not with shutil.copy ()....
On Windows os.rename will not  replace the destination file if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

*I troubleshooted the above issue and that code is working fine even if the same file name exist it will overwrite it new data and no error will come*

```
        original_file_name = 'Second.xlsx'
        new_file_name = self.FinalName + ".xlsx"
        orig_file_path = presentdirectory
        new_file_path = self.Folderpath
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(orig_file_path, original_file_name), os.path.join(new_file_path, new_file_name))
```